# Apply directive on click event in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tinymce

I want to apply one directive to DOM on click event, but I am not able to achieve same can someone point out to the mistake which I am making in fiddle.

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/laxmisalunkhe/s0nx5Lpp/

Example: I have class `editable` which will be used to get all HTML elements with that class and apply another directive (i.e. tinymce). I have used combination of both JQuery and AngularJS but not able to figure out the solution. Can Anybody help me out?

Actually I don't only want to apply tinymce directive on button click there will be some more different directives those will also get applied on different DOM elements, so it's not specific to tinymce, still it will be very helpful if someone point out to specific solution for tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

```
restrict: 'E',   //change the E to A, you use it as attribute.
```